# does camel azure blob component support proxy as a uri option

Tags: apache-camel

The camel http component allows you to set proxy at the route level as options, or also at the context level.

```
getContext().globalOptions().put("http.proxyHost", "172.168.18.9");
getContext().globalOptions().put("http.proxyPort" "8080");
```

The camel azure blob component also internally makes an https call. But there is no way to set proxy at URI level like the http component. Setting the proxy in system properties works. But we were wondering, if it would be feasible to support this as the component options.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's not possible: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-azure/src/main/docs/azure-blob-component.adoc

We can think about adding option like this one.

Comment: You can raise a JIRA on Apache Camel project for this option.

Comment: yeah. Thanks. I had seen the documentation and did not find any such option. I had seen a similar option with the HTTP component. I tried setting the proxy properties in the global options inside the config method of a RouteBuilder.

Comment: I'll raise a JIRA for this.